# Restoring database from ruby backup gem backup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, backup, database-restore

I have managed to do scheduled backups for my web app's database using the backup gem for ruby on rails. How do I restore to the latest backup if the system crashes or if anything happens to the app? Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: Welcome on SO! As this is a platform for asking programming questions, would you be so nice to show us the code/approach you have been working on?

Comment: paste link to gem you working with

Comment: http://meskyanichi.github.io/backup/v4/  Here's the gem I have been working with

Comment: Basically I used that backup gem to create backups of a sqlite3 database. It then gives me a tar file which when extracted, gives a folder containing a sql file. How do I use restore my current database to that sql file? I think I have to code the restoration separately as a rake task but I'm not too sure on how to go about doing that. Also, my backups are stored locally. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Currently that gem doesn't support automated restore functionalities.

See discussion [here](https://github.com/backup/backup/issues/601) and follow/vote for [this issue](https://github.com/backup/backup-features/issues/28)